# Make Ints within a string bold - swift

Tags: swift, string, nsattributedstring

Hi I have a string that I'm displaying in a label that shows a time like this `"4hours 27mins 45secs"` and this can vary based on the time for example `"30mins 5secs"`

I want to style the Ints in the string so they are bold and the characters are light so it looks like this...

[image: screenshot]

I've done some searching and found I need to use some sort of attributed string, but everything I've found seems to use some sort of breaking character, or a standard prefix to detect.

As I don't have either is there a way to check if the character is an int and apply bold. Appreciate this might not be possible and would welcome a recommendation for changing my approach.

Still pretty new to coding/swift so any help appreciated!

Comment: what is your environment and targets? For example, ios, macos, using SwiftUI, using Xcode 13.2, swift 5.5 or older?

Comment: Hi, its iOS Xcode 13.2.1 I'm not using swift UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly done, you can use a Regular Expression to find the ranges of all the numbers. Then, on these ranges, you change the attribute for a bold font.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+", options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: attributedString.string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
matches.forEach {
    attributedString.addAttributes([.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)], range: $0.range)
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, you are a genius, thank you! Although relatively simple I was never going to work this one out for myself. Never used a regular Expression before either, very useful

Answer (score -2):

If your deployment target is iOS15 you can use the newly added `AttributedString` with markdown support, which is much simple than the very complicated to use `NSAttributedString`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring